# Proof Verification: $\binom{n}{k}$ is always a natural number if $0\leq k\leq n$ - Spivak's Calculus, Problem 2-3(b)

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, induction, binomial-coefficients

This is problem 3(b) from Spivak's Calculus 4th ed., Chapter 2:

> Prove that $\binom{n}{k}$ is always a natural number if $0\leq k\leq n$

This is my proof:

If $n=0, \binom{0}{0}= \frac{0!}{0!}=1$

$\therefore \binom{0}{0} \in \Bbb N$, so the statement holds true for $n=0$.

Assuming that the statement holds true for $n=m$ such that $$\binom{m}{0},\binom{m}{1},\binom{m}{2},...,\binom{m}{m-1},\binom{m}{m} \in \Bbb N$$

Then for $n=m+1$, it follows that $\binom{m+1}{k}\in\Bbb N$ since $\binom{m+1}{k}=\binom{m}{k-1}+\binom{m}{k}$ and $\binom{m}{k-1}$ or $\binom{m}{k}\in \Bbb N$ by assumption.

$\therefore$ It has been proven that if the statement holds true for $n=m$ then it must hold true for $n=m+1 \Rightarrow$ By the principle of mathematical induction, the statement must hold true for all $0\leq k\leq n$ and $k,n\in \Bbb Z^{\geq}$. I'm posting this proof as it is different to the one Spivak provides and I'm not sure if it makes sense. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

In your proof the case of $ k =m +1$ has  to be addressed separately.

Otherwise it is a good proof.

Comment: Ah, I see. Spivak defines $\binom{n}{n}=1$ so I thought that was needed. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Thank you for your attention and understanding.